# Permanently remove sidebar that pops up every time I open a tab in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, sidebar

How can I permanently remove the sidebar that pops up every time I open a tab in  Safari 9.1.3 on OS X El Capitan?

Comment: Try the solutions in [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/209114/88313).  There's quite a few questions about this topic so it's a good idea to use the search function to find other solutions that could help, too.

Answer (score 8):

Open a new tab, then go to View → Hide Sidebar ⇧⌘L.
The sidebar will be hidden on new tab pages until you show it again.

Answer (score 0):

Scouring the web on this one - the only thing that seems to work is putting your Dock on the left side of the screen, then disabling the auto show of the dock in the terminal.

The answer by grgarside doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is 5 years old probably because Mac has mainstreamed this issue by having the solution easily accessible, but for anyone who still doesn't know how to stop this random sidebar pop-up its pretty simple. View> Hide Sidebar. For me the issue started randomly and I did not know they have a simple on and off feature.