# Prevent the slide-out from appearing in fullscreen safari

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

In full-screen Safari 13.0.5, when I move my mouse cursor to the left of the window, a sidebar slides out showing my reading list and bookmarks.

Often I was intending to click something at the left of the window, or just accidentally moved my cursor there. Then the slideout ends up interrupting my action or blocking my view of the web page.

How do I stop this sidebar from appearing when my mouse is at the left of the display?

[This upvoted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245167/150109) for macOS El Capitan (apparently) doesn't work for me.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245167/341892 - did you try this already ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to stop this from happening with conventional methods (i.e. through settings or modifying a .plist file.) It has also been around since Safari 9 from what I can glean from my researches. Search on this site, and in Google in general, to find ways to 'trick' Safari by moving the Dock to the left side of the screen, changing some parameters through a `defaults write` command to a .plist file and setting up some trackpad swipes and whatnot. Complicated and ultimately a kludge.